# How to query ignite cache by java?

Tags: caching, ignite

I start ignite server by ./ignite.sh, start a ignite client by java code, and execute a query in java,

```
public class TOFListener {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    //cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
    IgniteCache<String, Object> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("TOFCache");
    ContinuousQuery<String, Object> qry = new ContinuousQuery<>();
    qry.setInitialQuery(new ScanQuery<>((k, v) -> "name".equals(k) || "shoulderWidthStdDev".equals(k)));
    qry.setLocalListener((evts) -> evts.forEach(e ->
            System.out.println("UpdatedValue, [key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue() + "]")));
    qry.setRemoteFilterFactory(() -> evts -> evts.getKey().equals("name") || evts.getKey().equals("shoulderWidthStdDev"));

    cache.query(qry);

}
```

}

but it occur exception like this:
[Exception01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSh2N.png)
[Exception02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtGEj.png) [Exception03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba8mK.png)

But when I start ignite server by java code, query is ok,
I do not know why, anyone can help me? Thanks...

Comment: There should be more lines of exception trace, please paste them all.

Comment: Yes, I have updated new exception trace, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class is absent on server node so your lambdas cannot be instantiated there.

You should either enable [Peer Class Loading](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/peer-class-loading), or deploy your code to server nodes as JARs.

Comment: Thanks for your focus, but if i comments cache.query(qry); , thereis no exception, and I try to start new Thread with lambda, no exception too, so it should not reference to lambdas, thank you!

Comment: Not all lambdas need to be sent over to different nodes. Some are run locally - these would work.